# Different indentation no error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
password = raw_input("Enter password: ")
if password == "1234":
  print "You logged in correctly!"
else:
    print "GTFO"
```

Though i give different indentations the code is working fine i'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: Why so?If different indentation we need to get error right!

Comment: I think he means they are at different levels of indentation. Not just different as in 'space' (& its length) vs 'tab'

Comment: @drj: Read the documentation: http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

Comment: The problem is only when you have different levels of indentation in one block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it will not be flagged as as IndentationError, sine any block of statement has to have at lease 1 space of indent

here your `if` and `else` are two different blocks, so it was indented anyway so the interpreter throws no error

```
if True:
 print 
elif True:
  print 
elif True:
   print 
elif True:
     print 
else:
         print
```

This will work without any problem

But if I try the following I will get `IndendationError`

```
if True:

    print ""
      print ""  # has different Indentation
    print ""
```

Answer (score 5):

[The Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) explains indentation. Here's a relevant excerpt:

> At the beginning of each logical line, the line’s indentation level is
>   compared to the top of the stack. If it is equal, nothing happens. If
>   it is larger, it is pushed on the stack, and one INDENT token is
>   generated. If it is smaller, it *must* be one of the numbers occurring
>   on the stack

In your code, since the indentation level is larger than the top of the stack (which is `0`), it is treated as a single indent. The `else:` line popped `2` off of the top of the stack, so the interpreter has no memory of your previous indentation level of `2`. It only knows that it's higher than the `0`.

Problems arise when you start mixing indentation within a block:

```
def foo():
    if True:
        return True
      return False  # Is this part of the if statement or not?
```

When the parser reaches `return False`, the stack contains `[4, 8]`. The next line has an indent of `6`, which is not contained in the stack and therefore generates an `IndentationError`.